# Eclipse - how to make a Maven + OSGI project?

Tags: eclipse, maven, osgi

I am new to OSGI and Maven and trying to figure out how to make a maven-osgi project in Eclipse. I have followed the tutorials and im able to make a maven project and also an OSGI project but I cant make a project that holds both of them.

As I understand the most important part of the OSGI project is manifest.mf. In my OSGI project I have this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Osgi
Bundle-SymbolicName: osgi
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: osgi.Activator
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0"
```

And the most importand part of an maven project is its pom.xml. In my maven project i have this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.videobet.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>quick</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>quick</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Now to combine these two I tried to make a maven project first and then edit the pom.xml so it would add the dependencies of an OSGI project and make the manifest.mf. For that I tried to add something like this:

```
 <plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>  
      <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
    </archive> 
  </configuration>
</plugin>  
<plugin>   
  <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>bundle-manifest</id>
      <phase>process-classes</phase>
      <goals>    
        <goal>manifest</goal>
      </goals>   
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

But I was unsuccessful. First of all I got an error like this:

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.4.0:manifest (execution: bundle-manifest, phase: process-classes)
```

and even if i could resolve that im not sure if that would work. I also found different plugins like tycho that should help with the task but i dont really want to use them. I want to keep things as standard as possible and do things myself so i would eventually understand what im doing :)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to set the packaging type to "bundle". And the maven-bundle-plugin generates the MANIFEST.MF and puts it into the Jar for you, there is no need to use a separate plugin to build the Jar again.

Comment: Sorry, didnt quite understand, can you dumb it down for me a little bit? :)

Comment: Take out the whole `<plugin>` section where it sasy maven-jar-plugin. Change `<packaging>jar</packaging>` to `<packaging>bundle</packaging>`

Answer (score 2):

There is a other way to create Bundles with Maven have a look on Maven Tycho.
If you want work and deploy with Eclipse Environment then you can also use this Tutorial:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html

This is the Manifest first approach. 
With Maven Tycho you can create your own P2 Repository (and also a ZIP file) for your different Applications to Import in other Eclipse RCP Environments.

Answer (score 0):

There is a video that helps getting started to make an application with Eclipse+Maven+OSGi at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JNH6JVmAcIQ&t=432s

The video starts with a fresh Eclipse and an empty maven project, so if you do the same steps, it should work for you.

Also, there is cookbook at http://cookbook.everit.org/
The goal of the cookbook to help people getting started with OSGi based on Maven (and optionally on Eclipse).

The cookbook has not been updated for a while as it was waiting for the [eclipse plugin](http://www.everit.org/eosgi-e4-plugin/). As the Eclipse plugin works now, the cookbook will be rewritten soon.